# PyMySQL with Flask: %d format: a number is required, not str with stored procedure

Tags: python-3.x, pymysql

After configuring [PyMySQL](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL) in Python, i fell over the issue that I cannot execute a stored procedure. `cursor.callproc('storingSystemCreateCategory', 'Test12444')` returns: `%d format: a number is required, not str`.

The procedure looks like:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE storingSystemCreateCategory(IN name VARCHAR(255))
 BEGIN
 INSERT INTO StoringSystem.Category(`createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `deleted`, `name`)
 VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, False, name);
 END //
DELIMITER ;
```

I'm using http://flask-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#usage together with the setup above.

How can I execute the procedure correctly?

Comment: I opened a github issue here: https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/issues/708

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traceback is very important information describe where the exception came from.
You must paste traceback, not only error message.

Comment: I will provide it soon.

Comment: Solution is here: https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/issues/708#issuecomment-402928126